# PHP operators problems

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, ternary

I am building a PHP script. From one form I get `min_salary` and `max_salary`. I am trying to get both of them as a string in a salary variable like

```
$salary = "min_salary TO max_salary";
```

If the min salary is not specified it should be set to `0`, similarly if max salary is not specified it should be set to `*`.

I have written the below code but am not getting anything when either of the fields are not provided.

```
$salary = (isset($data['min_salary']) ? $data['min_salary'] : 0) .' TO '. (isset($data['max_salary']) ? $data['max_salary']:'*');
```

Also I don't want to use `if then else` statements.

Comment: The code looks fine for me, what do you mean with "I have written the below code but not getting anything when any of the field is not provided." - what outputs var_dump($salary)

Comment: suppose that the min_salary input box is left blank and max_salary is given 10 then the output should be like "0 TO 10" but I am getting only "TO 10" :(

Comment: There is a difference between the methods "isset" an "empty" - be aware of it. If you want to check whether is empty replace "isset(.." with "!empty(..."

Comment: You're already using if-else statements. Did you try casting the min_salary variable to integer?

Comment: Thanks Flixer your answer works fine just replaced isset with !empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line would produce that code without using if/else statements (even though ternery operator are really syntactic sugar around if/else statements)

```
$salary = max(0,$data['min_salary']) . ' TO ' . ($data['max_salary'] > 0 ? $data['max_salary'] : '*');
```

You don't really want the same scripting for both values as one should fallback to `0` and the other to `*`. The problem with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
(isset($data['min_salary']) ? $data['min_salary'] : 0)
```

is that a variable can be set to an empty string `$data = ''` which would return `true`. I'd hazard you do not want this to happen.

Comment: Right, this may be an other alternative to right the same. But I got my answer thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Flixer and Felix for your answer it works fine after I replaced isset with !empty

```
$salary = (!empty($data['min_salary']) ? $data['min_salary'] : 0).' TO '. (!empty($data['max_salary']) ? $data['max_salary']:'*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the values to int:

```
$salary = (isset($data['min_salary']) ? (int)$data['min_salary'] : 0).' TO '...
```

Same for the second part...

Comment: Thanks but not work.
Anyways I got answer from Flixer.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement is valid and provides a string, it works as-is on my php server (php 5.3.7) with $data not defined or defined and containing only one value.

Maybe it's the way you use $salary that has a concern.